# Adding signed numbers in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, signed, addition, x86-16

I want to sum an array elements. This array contains positive and negative numbers.

```
array db 07, 00, -3, 10, -7, 14, 9, -5, -100


lea ax, data
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax

lea si, array
mov cx, [si] 
mov si, 0002h
xor ax, ax
xor dx, dx 
Addition:
mov bl, [si]
cmp bl, 00h
jl NEGATIVE
xor bh, bh ;
jmp NEXTT
NEGATIVE:
mov bh, 0ffh
NEXTT:
add ax, bx
adc dx, 0
add si, 1
loop Addition
```

The sum (`DX:AX`) using this code = 0003 FFAE H which is wrong. I think that the right answer is 
FFFFFFAE H.

**1- How can I fix this problem?**

**2- How can I know whether a number in a register (AX for example) is positive or negative?**

**I use emu8086**

Comment: Looks to me like the data coming in are treated as 16 bit numbers - in which case the answer (last 16 bits) is correct. There is no difference between "large unsigned positive numbers" and "negative" numbers, as far as the CPU is concerned. It only becomes an issue when you convert to floating point type, print it out, etc - and at that point you need to know whether you are representing an unsigned or signed integer.

Comment: I will use the answer to get the average of these values then to print the average.

Comment: In this case, you could simply set DX=0 and don't care about carry.

Comment: @valplo What if the mean is negative? This is about **signed** numbers, not **unsigned** numbers. Setting `dx` to zero will fail always in that case.

Comment: @Floris If the answer is a signed **16-bit** value stored in `ax`, 0xffae is obviously correct answer. However, if the answer should be a signed **32-bit** value stored in `dx:ax`, as in the code of OP, 3:0xffae is incorrect answer (it's 262062 in decimal) and 0xffff:0xffae is the correct answer (it's -82 in decimal).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you don't handle integer overflow appropriately. Carry flag is for **unsigned** addition and subtraction, but you want **signed** addition. Overflow flag is for signed addition, it's set always when the sign changes.

**Edit:** Previous untested code didn't work properly. Here's the corrected (and self-contained) code. Tested with MASM 6.11.

```
.model small
.stack 4096

.data
array_size      dw 7
array           db -3, 10, -7, 14, 9, -5, -100
numbers         db '0123456789abcdef'

.code
start:
        mov     ax,seg array_size ; lea ax, data
        mov     ds,ax
        mov     es,ax

        mov     cx,[array_size]   ; cx = array size in bytes.
        lea     si,array          ; si points to the array.

; number is computed in dx:bx.

        xor     dx,dx
        xor     bx,bx

adding_loop:
        mov     al,[si]           ; number is read in al.
        cbw                       ; cbw sign-extends al to ax.
        test    ax,ax             ; check the sign of the addend.
        js      negative

positive:                         ; the addend is positive.
        add     bx,ax             ; add.
        adc     dx,0              ; carry.
        jmp     next_number

negative:                         ; the addend is negative.
        neg     ax                ; ax = |ax|.
        sub     bx,ax             ; subtract.
        sbb     dx,0              ; borrow.

next_number:
        inc     si                ; next number.
        loop    adding_loop

; result now in dx:bx.

        mov     ax,bx             ; result now in dx:ax.

; the rest of the code is only for printing.

        push    bx                ; push lower word.
        mov     bx,dx             ; copy the upper word to bx.
        call    print_word_in_hexadecimal

        push    dx                ; push upper word.
        mov     ah,2
        mov     dl,':'
        int     21h               ; print ':'
        pop     dx                ; pop upper word.

        pop     bx                ; pop lower word.
        call    print_word_in_hexadecimal

        mov     ah,4ch
        int     21h

; input:        bx: word to be printed.
; output:       -
print_word_in_hexadecimal:
        push    bx
        push    cx
        push    dx
        mov     cl,4              ; count for rol.
        mov     ch,4              ; 4 nibbles in each word.
next_nibble:
        rol     bx,cl             ; rotate 4 bits to the left.
        push    bx                ; push rotated word.
        and     bx,0fh
        mov     dl,[bx+numbers]
        mov     ah,2              ; print character.
        int     21h
        pop     bx                ; pop rotated word.
        dec     ch
        jnz     next_nibble

        pop     dx
        pop     cx
        pop     bx
        ret
end start
```

The above code does the signed integer addition for 8-bit values (the 8-bit values are extended to 16-bit values). Register usage has been changed to allow usage of `cbw` for cleaner code. Adding negative numbers has been converted to subtraction, for simplicity. Hardcoded offset of array (`mov si, 0002h`, which works only if the array is located at offset 2) has been replaced with `lea si,array`:

```
size_of_array dw 7
array         db -3, 10, -7, 14, 9, -5, -100
```

And the corresponding changes in the code:

```
lea si, size_of_array ; or you can replace these 2 lines with:
mov cx, [si]          ; 1. mov cx,size_of_array (TASM/MASM syntax).
lea si, array
```

And how to check if a number is negative or positive? Well, you check the highest bit. For example, as in my code (`test` does logical AND but doesn't save the result, it only updates the flags):

```
        test    ax,ax    ; do logical AND for ax,ax but don't save the result.
        js      negative ; jumps if the number is negative.

positive:
        ; the number is positive.
        jmp     my_label

negative:
        ; the number is negative.

my_label:
```

Comment: Why did you decrement dx? 
I run your code but the result was 0000 FFB8 H (DX:AX)!
When 07 is added AX becomes 0000 H.

Comment: @ammarx Sorry, my mistake. See the edited and tested code above.

Comment: Thank you @nrz very much for taking the time. But Shouldn't we check if there is an overflow when we add numbers. For example when we add 0007H, AX and DX become 0000H. Here there isn't overflow, but shouldn't we check?

Comment: @ammarx I don't exactly understand what you mean with "when we add 0007H, AX and DX become 0000H". In x86 assembly, `add` instruction sets the overflow flag (OF) when the signed number is too small (addition of two negative signed numbers) or too big (addition of too positive signed numbers). Also, for positive signed numbers handling carry (with `adc`) is sufficient here, as the number is stored in `dx:bx`, not in `bx` only.

Comment: I mean that DX:AX = 0000 0000H after adding 0007 to DX:AX (when CX=5). Do you mean that **adc** and **sbb** guarantee that there will not be an overflow?

Comment: @ammarx If the sum is smaller than 2147483648 (-1*2^31) or bigger than 2147483647 (2^31-1), 32 bits (`dx:bx` in my code) is not enough for the sum. You can detect overflow by adding something like `jo too_big` after `adc dx,0` and `jo too_small` after `sbb dx,0`, `too_big:` and `too_small:` containing some error-handling code. You can also compute the sum with more than 32 bits, eg. 64-bit sum in `ax:bx:cx:dx` or 96-bit sum in `ax:bx:cx:dx:si:di` are completely possible, you only need more `adc`'s and `sbb`'s and some reorganizing of the code. The size of available memory is the hard limit.